# How can I access objects inside objects directly in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, require, modularity

Let's say that I have two files named `dbPerson.js` and `dbCar.js` both with their own methods like:

**dbPerson.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    getAll(callback){}
}
```

**dbCar.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    getOne(callback){}
}
```

And then I have another file named `db.js` that would import those files:

```
const dbPerson=require('./dbPerson');
const dbCar=require('./dbCar');
```

And ultimately I have a main file which imports `db.js`:

```
const db=require('./db');
```

I want to be able to call the methods by using `db.getAll()` and `db.getOne()`, but this way I would need to use `db.dbPerson.getAll()` and `db.dbCar.getOne()`, is there a way so I don't need to do that?

**UPDATE:** I found that the answer below helps me but thanks for everyone who tried to understand what I meant, next time I'm gonna try to be more clear!

Comment: You can, of course, merge these two objects, either using Object.assign, or using the new object spread syntax.

Comment: what do you export from `db.js` - that's the key ... e.g. `module.exports = {
    getAll : dbPerson.getAll,
    getOne: dbCar.getOne
};`

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda from what I've read I can't understand how the Object Spread Syntax could be used for non-arithmetic functions.

Comment: @Bravo But then that means I have to manually specify each method, it's not as practical!

Comment: @DarkCeptor44 Please see my answer below

Comment: It was a simple example answering exactly the code you posted that made  no mention of any other methods being exported

Comment: @Bravo when I said "both with their own methods" that's what I meant.

Comment: yes, and each has a method, like you said :p I misinterpreted the plural :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to do it. Which path you take should depend on your requirements.

First let's assume you want to merge these two objects(dbCar and dbPerson). Then you can do it simply using the object spread syntax.

```
// db.js
module.exports = {
  ...dbPerson,
  ...dbCar,
}
```

Note that doing this way, conflicting properties of dbPerson will be overridden by the properties of dbCar. And by the naming, it does not make sense to merge these two objects (What would you call something that is a Person and also a Car?).

Another approach is to use a proxy object to forward the calls.

```
// db.js
module.exports = {
  getAll: dbPerson.getAll,
  getOne: dbCar.getOne,
}
```

Comment: The first way is exactly what I want, the thing is I'm working with database and coming from MVC in Java I basically just want to do one file for each table of the database, each having their methods like getPerson, addPerson and so on, and then only import the resulting file instead of each one individually, I suppose in a way it's similar to an interface.

Answer (score 1):

You would need need to export those functions from your `db.js` file too:

```
//db.js
const dbPerson=require('./dbPerson');
const dbCar=require('./dbCar');

module.exports = {
    getAll: dbPerson.getAll, 
    getOne: dbCar.getOne
}
```

You say:

> I want to be able to call the methods by using db.getAll() and db.getOne(), but this way I would need to use db.dbPerson.getAll() and db.dbCar.getOne(), is there a way so I don't need to do that?

Is there a reason that this would be a problem?

As far as I can see - you are talking about two different *things*, cars and people.

Doing `db.dbCar.getOne()` makes sense to me, if I did `db.getOne()`, I wouldn't be sure whether I'm getting one car or one person.

You could just rename the methods in your export, like:

```
module.exports {
    getAllPersons: dbPerson.getAll, 
    getOneCar: dbCar.getOne, 
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this answer is wrong. If you export it that way, you still need to reference these properties through the dbPerson and dbCar objects

Comment: I'd say that's exactly how it is being exported now, meaning you access using `db.dbPerson.getAll`

Comment: @dwjohnston you're right I used the wrong names for the methods, it should've been getPerson and getCar.